# [tag]ERROR [tag]Image Error loading <graphics/Untitled.mkv> the video plays without problem but I want to get rid of to error I am receiveing. How?

Tags: python, image, video, kivy

I use kivy downbelow there is my code. I pip installed ffpyplayer and pillow. But in order to not recieve any errors in build I wanted to over come this error.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.video import Video

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        video = Video(source='graphics/Untitled.mkv')
        video.state='play'
        video.options = {'eos': 'stop'}
        video.allow_stretch=True
        return video

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```